# How to add Icons to navigation drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I know how to add Icons to a custom drawer navigation, I wonder if there is any way to add icons directly to `</Drawer.Navigator>` or `<Drawer.Screen/>`?

For example this is my code:

```
const MyDrawer=()=>{

const Drawer=createDrawerNavigator();

return(

<NavigationContainer>
  <Drawer.Navigator
  initialRouteName='Main Page'
  >

<Drawer.Screen  name='Main Page' component={MainFunc} />


</Drawer.Navigator>

</NavigationContainer>
)
```

Answer (score 7):

For add, a custom icon to an item, create one function to display a list of drawer item

like this

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem
      icon={({ focused, color, size }) => <Icon color={color} size={size} name={focused ? 'heart' : 'heart-outline'} /> )}
      label="Help"
       onPress={() => alert('Link to help')} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

`<DrawerItem>` has different properties like label, icon, onPress etc you can

so final code be

```
const MyDrawer=()=>{

const Drawer=createDrawerNavigator();

return(

<NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName='Main Page'
      drawerContent={props => CustomDrawerContent(props)}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen  name='Main Page' component={MainFunc} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
)



function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem
      icon={({ focused, color, size }) => <Icon color={color} size={size} name={focused ? 'heart' : 'heart-outline'} /> )}
      label="Help"
       onPress={() => alert('Link to help')} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

you can [visit here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html) more info

Comment: I am using native base and imported``` Icon``` through native base path, Your solution didn't work

Comment: for that you can try this 
<Icon name={"icon-name"} type={"type of icon"} color={"black"} fontSize={22} />
you can find icon type and name here https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/ and also you need to install react-native-vector-icon package

Comment: @rajantank how to reduce the space between the icon and the text?

Answer (score 0):

As per the code in question, you should have:

```js
import AntDesign from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign";

const MyDrawer=()=>{

const Drawer=createDrawerNavigator();

return(

<NavigationContainer>
  <Drawer.Navigator
  initialRouteName='Main Page'
  >
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="Main Page"
      component={MainFunc}
      options={{
        drawerIcon: () => (
          <AntDesign name="dashboard" size={30} color="black" />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
)
```

**NOTE:** The `drawer.screen` `options` prop and `drawerIcon` implementation and the icon import as well.

Here's a link to a more elaborate example: [An answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77584198/16946743)